# How to subclass an OrderedDict?

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass, ordereddictionary

Subclassing a Python `dict` works as expected:

```
>>> class DictSub(dict):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self[1] = 10
...         
>>> DictSub()
{1: 10}
```

However, doing the same thing with a `collections.OrderedDict` does not work:

```
>>> import collections
>>> class OrdDictSub(collections.OrderedDict):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self[1] = 10
...         
>>> OrdDictSub()
(…)
AttributeError: 'OrdDictSub' object has no attribute '_OrderedDict__root'
```

Thus, the OrderedDict implementation uses a private `__root` atribute, which prevents the subclass `OrdDictSub` from behaving like the `DictSub` subclass.  Why?  How can one inherit from an OrderedDict?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to invoke `OrderedDict.__init__` from your `__init__`:

```
class OrdDictSub(collections.OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self):
        super(OrdDictSub, self).__init__()
```

You haven't given `OrderedDict` a chance to initialize itself.  Technically, you want to do this for your `dict` subclass as well, since you want a fully initialized `dict`.  The fact that `dict` works without it is just luck.

Comment: Thanks. My bad, indeed. It is true that I was influenced by dict. I even asked a question about dict some time ago (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033150/subclassing-dict-should-dict-init-be-called)!

Comment: don't you want args and kwargs in init? `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrdDictSub, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: You forgot to add the `*args, **kwds` and transfer them into the `__init__` method, but this answer is correct about the need to invoke `__init__`.

Answer (score 2):

Try initializing the superclass in the `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self):
    collections.OrderedDict.__init__(self)
    self[1] = 10
```

This is the normal way to initialize a subclass.  You don't *have* to call the superclass's `__init__` method in general, but if you have no knowledge of the superclass's implementation you really should call `__init__`.

Comment: Use `super()` to call methods of superclass

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Good answer, but using `super()` is not a matter of style: it is important to use it (instead of using an explicit superclass) in case your own class is subclassed. Example of reference: http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/. Furthermore, using `super()` makes the code at tad easier to maintain (it is easier to change the name of the class).

Comment: @EOL: I can accept that `super()` is the way to go, but I disagree with your "furthermore": I'd say it's six of one and half dozen of the other, *in Python 2*. If you want to change the name of your `OrdDictSub` class but still keep the same parent, then using `super()` means you have to do it in two places instead of just one. On the other hand, if you want to keep the `OrdDictSub` name but change the parent, then *not* using `super()` means you have to do it in two places rather than one. Fortunately, this was fixed in Python 3 (just call `super()` without parameters).

Comment: @JohnY: Agreed, about `super()` not being more convenient in case of class name changes in Python 2, but only in Python 3.

Comment: @JohnY: Well, I tested it, and using `self.__class__` is wrong, because `self.__class__` always gives the actual class!  Here is a demo you can try yourself, it will throw a `RuntimeError` when it exceeds the maximum recursion depth: https://gist.github.com/depp/87a5f1079556eb0ed07e

Comment: @JohnY: But you can only know that it's safe if you know that your class will never be subclassed, which I don't think is a very good assumption most of the time.

Comment: @JohnY: It's incorrect to say that if you use `super()`, others are screwed if they don't.  You can mix `super()` and direct base class calls just fine, as long as you don't do this in a class with multiple paths to a base class (in which case you *have* to use `super()`).  The only one that always breaks in common cases is `super(self.__class__, self)`, which is why you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @JohnY: This excellent answer by Martijn Pieters covers it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18208725/82294 -- if you think Martijn is wrong, go argue over there.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: OK, fair enough. It is indeed a very nice explanation by Martijn. I've removed some of my comments here, as I believe they are not helpful to future readers, even in a historical capacity (except to serve as evidence of my ignorance).