# When calling super() in a derived class, can I pass in self.__class__?

Tags: python, python-2.7, super

I've recently discovered (via StackOverflow) that to call a method in a base class I should call:

`super([[derived class]], self).[[base class method]]()`

That's fine, it works.  However, I find myself often copying and pasting between classes when I make a change and frequently I forget to fix the derived class argument to the super() function.

I'd like to avoid having to remember to change the derived class argument.  Can I instead just use `self.__class__` as the first argument of the super() function?

It seems to work but are there good reasons why I shouldn't do this?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

No you cannot. The `super()` call needs to know what class the method is part of, to search the base classes for an overridden method.

If you pass in `self.__class__` (or better still, `type(self)`) then `super()` is given the *wrong* starting point to search for methods, and will end up calling *its own method again*.

See it as a pointer in the list of classes that form the Method Resolution Order sequence. If you pass in `type(self)` then the pointer will refer to any subclasses instead of the original starting point.

The following code leads to an infinite recursion error:

```
class Base(object):
    def method(self):
        print 'original'

class Derived(Base):
    def method(self):
        print 'derived'
        super(type(self), self).method()

class Subclass(Derived):
    def method(self):
        print 'subclass of derived'
        super(Subclass, self).method()
```

Demo:

```
>>> Subclass().method()
subclass of derived
derived
derived
derived

<... *many* lines removed ...>

  File "<stdin>", line 4, in method
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in method
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in method
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

because `type(self)` is `Subclass`, **not** `Derived`, in `Derived.method()`.

In the example, the MRO for `Subclass` is `[Subclass, Derived, Base]`, and `super()` needs to know where to start searching for any overridden methods. By using `type(self)` you tell it to start at `Subclass`, so it'll find `Derived.method()` next, which is where we started.

Comment: Excellent, very clear, explanation, thanks.

Answer (score 13):

`self.__class__` might *not* be a subclass, but rather a grandchild-or-younger class, leading to a stack-breaking loop.