# The difference between super().method() versus super(self.__class__,self).method()

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Here is the code I was trying to write:

```
class A(object):
    def bind_foo(self):
        old_foo = self.foo
        def new_foo():
            old_foo()
            #super().foo()
            super(self.__class__,self).foo()

        self.foo = new_foo

    def __init__(self):
        print("A __init__")          

    def foo(self):
        print("A foo")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("B __init__")
        super().__init__()

    def foo(self):
        print("B foo")
        super().foo()

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("C __init__")
        super().__init__()
        super().bind_foo()

    def foo(self):
        print("C foo")    

b  = B()
b.foo()

c = C()
c.foo()
```

Class B and A is the expected behavior, that is, when I call `b.foo()`, it calls `a.foo()` as well with `super()`. Class C is the trying to mimic the child B and parent A behavior but this time I dont want to put explicitly `super().foo()` in the child class but I still want the parent `foo()` to be called. It works as expected.

However, what I dont quite get is that, under `A.bind_foo`, I have to use `super(self.__class__,self).foo()` rather than `super().foo`. `super().foo` gives a

```
"SystemError: super(): no arguments".
```

Can someone explain why that is so?

Comment: What you're doing in `bind_foo` is wrong. `super(self.__class__, self).foo()` is actually calling `foo` on the first superclass of the actual instance. So, if you had `class B(A)`, then `class C(B)`, then `class D(C)`, and did `D().bind_foo()`, you'd end up calling the `C` implementation. That can't what you want. If you want to call the `D` implementation, just call `self.foo()`. If you want to call the `A` implementation, call `A.foo(self)`.

Comment: Ideally in that case I want the `D` to call its own implementation, then `C` then `B` then `A`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should *not* use `self.__class__` or `type(self)` when calling `super()`.

In Python 3, a call to `super()` without arguments is equivalent to `super(B, self)` (within methods on class `B`); note the *explicit* naming of the class. The Python compiler adds a `__class__` closure cell to methods that use `super()` without arguments (see [Why is Python 3.x's super() magic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608134/why-is-python-3-xs-super-magic)) that references the *current class* being defined.

If you use `super(self.__class__, self)` or `super(type(self), self)`, you will hit an infinite recursion exception when a subclass tries to call that method; at that time `self.__class__` is *the derived class*, not the original. See [When calling super() in a derived class, can I pass in self.__class__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208683/when-calling-super-in-a-derived-class-can-i-pass-in-self-class)

So, to summarize, in Python 3:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("B __init__")
        super().__init__()

    def foo(self):
        print("B foo")
        super().foo()
```

is equal to:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("B __init__")
        super(B, self).__init__()

    def foo(self):
        print("B foo")
        super(B, self).foo()
```

but you should use the former, as it saves you repeating yourself.

In Python 2, you are stuck with the second form *only*.

For your `bind_foo()` method, you'll have to pass in an explicit class from which to search the MRO from, as the Python compiler cannot determine here what class is used when you bind the new replacement `foo`:

```
def bind_foo(self, klass=None):
    old_foo = self.foo
    if klass is None:
        klass = type(self)

    def new_foo():
        old_foo()
        super(klass, self).foo()

    self.foo = new_foo
```

You *could* use `__class__` (no `self`) to have Python provide you with the closure cell, but that'd be a reference to `A`, not `C` here. When you are binding the new `foo`, you want the search for overridden methods in the MRO to start searching at `C` instead.

Note that if you now create a class `D`, subclassing from `C`, things will go wrong *again*, because now you are calling `bind_foo()` and in turn call `super()` with `D`, not `C`, as the starting point. Your best bet then is to call `bind_foo()` with an *explicit* class reference. Here `__class__` (no `self.`) will do nicely:

```
class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("C __init__")
        super().__init__()
        self.bind_foo(__class__)
```

Now you have the same behaviour as using `super()` without arguments, a reference to the *current* class, the one in which you are defining the method `__init__`, is passed to `super()`, making the `new_foo()` behave as if it was defined directly in the class definition of `C`.

Note that there is no point in calling `bind_foo()` on `super()` here; you didn't override it here, so you can just call `self.bind_foo()` instead.

Comment: So how would I solve the problem I have at hand then with child C?

Comment: I suspect the no-argument `super` doesn't work in the definition of `new_foo` because that's not a method (just a regular function being assigned to an instance variable). It's probably a bad idea to mix inheritance-style method overloading (where you can call `super`) with instance variable overloading.

Comment: @Blckknght: you really don't want to have the automatic class used there; you want to determine the class at call time (so when `bind_foo()` is called, *not* when the `bind_foo()` function object is created).

Comment: Thanks for the help! Suppose if I want `D` to inherent from `C`, `C` from `B` and `B` from `A`; but I want the `D's` foo to call `D's` implementation, then `C's`, then `B's`, then `A's`. Whats the best way to do so?

Comment: @NoHarmInTrying: by giving each class a `foo` implementation that does the right thing; call `super().foo()`. Also see [Raymond Hettinger's blog post on `super()` use](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/). That's what `super()` is for, cooperative class design.

Comment: Is it not possible without explicitly putting `super()` in every `foo()`?

Comment: @NoHarmInTrying: you could loop over `type(self).mro()` and see for each class if there is a `foo` attribute, then call that function directly passing in `self`. You would not use `super()` there, that is not what `super()` is *for*.

Comment: I didnt know know `type(self).mro()` existed, that help things greatly. Thanks!