# How to get class when I can't use self - Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, python-3.x

I have one weird problem. I have following code:

```
class A:
    def f():
        return __class__()

class B(A):
    pass
a = A.f()
b = B.f()
print(a, b)
```

And output is something like this:

```
<__main__.A object at 0x01AF2630> <__main__.A object at 0x01B09B70>
```

So how can I get `B` instead of second `A`?

Comment: `how can I get B instead of second A` - What do you mean by that? An instance of `B`?

Comment: In printed text. What I meant is that `b` becomes instance of `B`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [magic `__class__` closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776056/the-difference-between-super-method-versus-superself-class-self-method/19776143#19776143) is set for the *method context* and only really meant for use by `super()`.

For methods you'd want to use `self.__class__` instead:

```
return self.__class__()
```

or better still, use `type(self)`:

```
return type(self)()
```

If you want to be able to call the method on a class, then use the [`classmethod` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) to be handed a reference to the class object, rather than remain unbound:

```
@classmethod
def f(cls):
    return cls()
```

`classmethod`s are always bound to the class they are called on, so for `A.f()` that'd be `A`, for `B.f()` you get handed in `B`.

Comment: @thefourtheye: right, then using a `@classmethod` is the right way to go about it.

Comment: `@classmethod` is excellent, I did't use `self.__class__()` because I couldn't use `self`. I always thought `@classmethod` use object not class.