# When running a method from a Python superclass, how can I know the name of the child class that invoked it?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, superclass

Let's say I have this parent class:

```
class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # I want to assign the name of the class that called
        # the super class in a variable.
        cls.child_class_name = ??
        # Do some more stuff...
```

And I have this class that inherits from the BaseTestCase class above:

```
class MyTestCase(BaseTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # Call SetUpClass from parent (BaseTestCase)
        super(cls, cls).setUpClass()
        # Do more stuff...
```

Since many classes can inherit from the same parent class. How can I know the name of the class that invoked the parent class in a given time?

I hope my question make sense. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cls.__name__` is always the name of the current class, because `cls` is bound the actual class object on which the class method was called.

In other words, `cls` is *not* a reference to the class on which the method is defined.

Note that you should **not** use `super(cls, cls)`! That'll lead to [infinite recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208683/when-calling-super-in-a-derived-class-can-i-pass-in-self-class/18208725#18208725) if you were to create a derived class from `MyTestCase`! Use the actual class, always:

```
class MyTestCase(BaseTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # Call SetUpClass from parent (BaseTestCase)
        super(MyTestCase, cls).setUpClass()
        # Do more stuff...
```

Demo:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     @classmethod
...     def spam(cls):
...         print(cls.__name__)
... 
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...     @classmethod
...     def spam(cls):
...         super(Bar, cls).spam()
... 
>>> Bar.spam()
Bar
>>> Foo.spam()
Foo
```