# Django models: managing transactions when commit_manually is deprecated

Tags: python, django, django-models, overriding

I'm running Django 1.4.11. I overrode the `save()` method of a Django model in a way similar to the following code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import transaction

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # model definition

    @transaction.commit_manually
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            foo() # do_other_things
        except:
            transaction.rollback()
            raise
        else:
            transaction.commit()
```

When I run my code, sometimes I read this message in the Apache log:

> RemovedInDjango18Warning: commit_manually is deprecated in favor of
>   set_autocommit.

How can I implement the same logic with set_autocommit?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use `self.__class__` in `super()`. See this answer for an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18208725/2615075

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The same logic would look like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import transaction

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # model definition

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        transaction.set_autocommit(False)
        try:
            super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            foo() # do_other_things
        except:
            transaction.rollback()
            raise
        else:
            transaction.commit()
        finally:
            transaction.set_autocommit(True)
```

However, this would be equivalent to using the `atomic()` decorator:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import transaction

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # model definition

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        foo() # do_other_things
```

This will commit the transaction on a successful `__exit__`, and roll back in the case of an exception.

Comment: Perfect. So if foo() or anything else inside `save()` method raises an exception, the commit on the DBMS of the super `save()` does not take place. Right?

Comment: That's right, unless the exception is caught within the atomic block.

Answer (score 1):

For the example you have given you can just use [`transaction.atomic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic)
. If the code succeeds, the entire transaction will be committed. If there's an exception, the changes will be rolled back.

```
@transaction.atomic
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    foo() # do_other_things
```