# Django executing backward relation query occurred a maximum recursion depth exceeded error when I use Manager

Tags: python, django, recursion, model

Here's the code:

class CarSource

```
class CarSource(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    dealer = models.ForeignKey(Dealer, blank=True, null=True, \
                  on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='cars', \
                  verbose_name=u'dealer own this car')
    objects = CarSourceManager()
```

class Dealer

```
class Dealer(models.Model):
    ...
```

class CarSourceManager:

```
class CarSourceManager(models.Manager):
    ''' Manage query in CarSource, filter data that was processed successfully.'''
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(self.__class__, self).get_query_set().filter(status='S')
```

When I execute this:

```
from ... import Dealer
d = Dealer.objects.get(id = 2)
d.cars.all()
```

It occur error as below:

```
File "/...path..of..error..file../apps/car/managers.py", line 9, in all
return super(self.__class__, self).all().filter(status='S')
File "/...path..of..error..file../apps/car/managers.py", line 9, in all
return super(self.__class__, self).all().filter(status='S')
File "/...path..of..error..file../apps/car/managers.py", line 9, in all
return super(self.__class__, self).all().filter(status='S')
File "/...path..of..error..file../apps/car/managers.py", line 9, in all
return super(self.__class__, self).all().filter(status='S')
File "/...path..of..error..file../apps/car/managers.py", line 9, in all
return super(self.__class__, self).all().filter(status='S')
File "/...path..of..error..file../apps/car/managers.py", line 9, in all
return super(self.__class__, self).all().filter(status='S')
File "/...path..of..error..file../apps/car/managers.py", line 9, in all
return super(self.__class__, self).all().filter(status='S')
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I overwrite the `get_query_set` of `models.Manager` in `CarSourceManager`, obviously, it continue call it self recursively. I've watched the code of Manager but can't figure it out, please help me.

Comment: By the way, My django version is 1.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18208725/1085511

Basically you can not use

```
super(self.__class__, self)
```

Use

```
super(CarSourceManager, self)
```

instead.

The related manager's `self.__class__` is different from `CarSourceManager` therefore the loop.

Comment: haaa, it works!! thx very much, but I'm new to stackoverflow, have no reputation, can't upvote ur answer. Sorry about that. seems that I still need to learn python hard.;) thank u again!

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly why you have to name the class explicitly when you call super:

```
return super(CarSourceManager, self).get_query_set().filter(status='S')
```

Comment: Yeah! thank u, u are right. I'm new to stackoverflow, have no reputation, can't upvote ur answer. Sorry about that. I will upvote later.