# Python inheritance: create child object in parent class

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a parent class, with a method that returns a new object. I'd like that object to be of the same type as self (ie Parent if called within Parent class, Child if called in a Child instance).

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self,param):
        self.param = param

    def copy(self):
        new_param = some_complicated_stuff(self.param)
        return Parent(new_param)

class Child(Parent):
    pass

C = Child(param)
D = C.copy()
```

Here `D = C.copy()` will be of type Parent, regardless of the class `C`. I would like to have copy return an instance of the same class as `C`, while keeping the "some_complicated_stuff" part in the parent class in order to avoid code duplicate.

Context: Parent is an abstract group structure, "copy" returns subgroups (doing a series of algebraic operations), and I have many different Child classes that use this method.

Comment: `type(self)(new_param)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the fact that every instance has a pointer to its class under `__class__`:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self,param):
        self.param = param

    def copy(self):
        new_param = some_complicated_stuff(self.param)
        return self.__class__(new_param)
```

This will be `Parent` for the above class, but `Child` in the derived class.

Instead of `self.__class__`, you can also use `type(self)`, as [@Eli Korvigo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3846213/eli-korvigo) has said [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48626989/python-inheritance-create-child-object-in-parent-class/48627051#comment84250955_48626989), or as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18208725/4042267).