# Accessing OrderedDict keys like attributes in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to write a container class which

1. allows both indexing (in the dictionary style), e.g. `data['a']` and attribute-like access e.g. `data.a` ; this is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984647/accessing-dict-keys-like-an-attribute-in-python)
2. preserves the order in which entries where added, e.g. by subclassing `collections.OrderedDict` ; this is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174702/how-to-subclass-an-ordereddict?lq=1)

I adapted the solution for 1. to subclass `collections.OrderedDict` instead of `dict` but it does not work; see below.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class mydict(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(mydict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self

D = mydict(a=1, b=2)

#D['c'] = 3 # fails
D.d    = 4

#print D    # fails
```

The two lines with the failure comment cause the following errors:

```
    print D
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 176, in __repr__
    return '%s(%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.items())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 113, in items
    return [(key, self[key]) for key in self]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 76, in __iter__
    root = self.__root
AttributeError: 'struct' object has no attribute '_OrderedDict__root'
```

and

```
    D['c'] = 3
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 58, in __setitem__
    root = self.__root
AttributeError: 'mydict' object has no attribute '_OrderedDict__root'
```

Is there a solution to this ? Can the `__init__` function be patched ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, if you just want to get this working, not understand what's wrong with your attempt, there are multiple "AttrDict" implementations on PyPI, ActiveState, etc. Search for one and look at its code—or just install it and use it.

---

That `self.__dict__ = self` is not what you want. I realize that people recommend it, but it has some fundamental major problems. And one of those problems is exactly the one you're seeing.

In particular, it means you've now lost all of your existing attributes, including internal attributes used by `OrderedDict` itself (like that `__root` that you're getting errors about) and special attributes attached to all objects (like `__class__`).

When you're just using `dict` you don't notice this problem—at least in CPython—because `dict` is implemented in C, and the special members that it needs to operate are stored in a C struct, not in the `__dict__`, so you can't lose them. But for any class implemented in Python that needs any special members, the problem becomes visible.

---

Python has special methods for [customizing attribute access](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access). What you want to do is implement those methods:

```
class AttrDict(OrderedDict):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self[name]
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self[name] = value
    def __delattr__(self, name):
        del self[name]
```

---

However, in this case, even that won't work for everything, because you're still going to get your overrides called when the code in `OrderedDict` tries to use `__root`! To fix that you need to forward only *some* calls in these methods to your dict, not *all* of them.

And that "some" is complicated and hard to get right. A much simpler solution would be to just encapsulate and delegate to an `OrderedDict` instead of inheriting:

```
class AttrDict(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._od = OrderedDict(*args, **kwargs)
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self._od[name]
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == '_od':
            self.__dict__['_od'] = value
        else:
            self._od[name] = value
    def __delattr__(self, name):
        del self._od[name]
```

Or, more simply, just use an OrderedDict as your `__dict__`—which is the paradigm case for a metaclass, but if you want to do it quick&dirty, you can do it in `__init__` or `__new__` instead.

---

The latter solutions just make you into a normal object with attributes that happen to be ordered, not a mapping at all. But it's pretty easy to forward the mapping methods as well. Implement `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, `__iter__`, and `__len__` to forward to `self._od`, and inherit from [`collections.MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) to fill in the rest of the API.

And now, if you go back and look up "AttrDict" on PyPI and click on the implementations, you'll see that this is exactly what they all do: they forward both `__getattr__` and `__getitem__` to an OrderedDict's `__getitem__`, and so on.

Comment: I had long seen the two approaches to implement a `AttrDict`, thought they where equivalent and chose the wrong one for its concision. Thanks for highlighting the difference and for all the details.

Comment: @wap26: It really is a hack, and I don't think people should be teaching it to people who don't understand why it works. (If you _do_ understand how it works, and you also understand descriptors, you can probably figure out the workaround yourself… and also a way  to make the cleaner version nicer.)