# correct way to add custom (deep) copying logic to a python class

Tags: python

i am implementing a python class that provides some nested data structure. i want to add support for copying through `copy.copy()` and deep copying through `copy.deepcopy()`, which, as the [docs for the copy module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) describe, involves writing `__copy__()` and `__deepcopy__` special methods.

i know how to teach my class to make a copy of itself, but i want to avoid going through `__init__()` on the new instance, since `__init__()` does some things that my copying logic does not want (or need) to do.

what i ended up with is this method, which works as intended:

```
def __copy__(self):
    cls = type(self)
    obj = cls.__new__(cls)
    # custom copying logic that populates obj goes here
    return obj
```

my question is: is calling `cls.__new__(cls)` the right approach for a `__copy__()` implementation that wants to skip `__init__()` for the copy? or is there a more "pythonic" approach that i overlooked?

Comment: The only alternative I can think of is to remove the stuff you don't want running more than once from `__init__` and putting it in some other method instead. That way your calling code can choose whether or not to run that part after creating an instance.

Comment: You might add a copy flag parameter to the `init` so as to differentiate the different initializations. Right now, if you make changes to your class, you would always have to check two methods..

Comment: the __init__() signature is fixed and cannot grow any more (keyword) arguments since the constructor eats all *args and **kwargs to populate the data structure (same behaviour as the dict() constructor).

Comment: It should be possible to pop special kwargs from the dict and handle them separately...right?

Comment: nope, since the constructor takes *args and **kwargs like dict() so __init__() is completely "taken".

Comment: I mean rewriting the constructor... so that is doesn't "take" every kwarg, but first pops off a few things. I believe I mean [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033554/5067311). (Also: if you don't @notify other users, they won't see a notification of your comment)

Comment: @AndrasDeak that would mean that that special argument cannot be used for other purposes, which is wrong in this case, since my constructor behaves like the dict() constructor and must not treat any of its arguments in a special way.

Comment: How close to the behaviour of the dict constructor? You could use a non-hashbable special key that is not allowed to be a key in a dict. But obviously this hinges on your class behaving similarly to dicts.

Comment: @AndrasDeak exactly the same as a dict since it is supposed to be a dict with fancy extra features for nested lookups and type checking. (open source, not yet publicized, but available on my github.)

Comment: @wouterbolsterlee I see that you [rolled back my approved edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44231316/revisions) to add the [tag:copy] and [tag:deep-copy] tags along with some general cleanup. Is there a reason why you did this?

Comment: sorry, removing tags was unintentional. what i meant to roll back is random capitalisation "fixes" to stuff i wrote. that is not how i write (for various reasons not relevant here) yet my sig is below it, so if that is literally the only thing that "improves" i consider it unwanted interference with my writing style. it annoys me if random strangers change things with my name on them with no valuable contribution but pedantry. it also wastes my time with useless notifications, so i actively discourage that practice by reverting those changes. nothing personal, but i alone decide how i write :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is more pythonic, but you could use a flag.

```
from collections import Mapping
from copy import copy, deepcopy


class CustomDict(dict, Mapping):
    _run_setup = True

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._dict = dict(*args, **kwargs)
        if args and isinstance(args[0], CustomDict):
            self._run_setup = args[0]._run_setup
        if self._run_setup:
            print("Doing some setup stuff")
        else:
            try:
                print("Avoiding some setup stuff")
            finally:
                self._run_setup = True

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._dict[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._dict)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._dict)

    def __copy__(self):
        self._run_setup = False
        try:
            copied_custom_dict = CustomDict(self)
        finally:
            self._run_setup = True
        return copied_custom_dict
```

In the `__init__` above, the conditional setup stuff is only done if `_run_setup = True`. The only way to avoid this is by calling `CustomDict` with the first parameter being an instance of itself with `_run_setup = False`. This way, it's easy to flip the setup switch in different methods.

The `try...finally` blocks look clunky to me, but it's a way to make sure every method starts and ends with `_run_setup = True`.

Comment: to me it seems that CustomDict(some_other_custom_dict_instance) is perfectly normal so that should exhibit "standard" behaviour. that means "if args and isinstance(args[0], CustomDict):" is not a test that can be used, i think.

Comment: hmm discard my previous comment since the _original_ is temporarily modified to set the flag. that is indeed a way to propagate the flag. but mutating state for a read-only operation _feels_ wrong, and will break with multi-threading.