# Subclassing a list on python

Tags: python, list, super

I am following a tutorial online and the code is this:

```
class Hands(list):
    def __init__(self, size=0, die_class=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if not die_class:
            raise ValueError("You must provide a die class")
        super().__init__()

        for _ in range(size):
            self.append(die_class())
```

It basically models a player with a number of dice (`size`) and what dice they are holding (`die_class`).

My confusion is why do we need to call `super().__init__`? I tried running the code without it and it worked fine! Why is the call necessary?

Comment: even if it works now because `list` doesn't seem to need a default constructor, what if the next python versions require `__init__` to be called on a `list` object? why _not_ calling `__init__` ?

Comment: It's not necessary (but it's good practice), see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/318165/is-calling-the-superclass-constructor-in-a-subclass-really-important

Comment: I think it breaks Liskov principle. it works, okay, but when will it break?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subclassing dict: should dict.\_\_init\_\_() be called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033150/subclassing-dict-should-dict-init-be-called)

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the `__init__()` if the base class to be sure any initialisation code there is run.  That it (seems) to work without that call can be a coincidence, or you may simply haven't hit the resulting problem yet.  Even if it works consistently in the Python version and implementation you are using currently, it isn't guaranteed for other versions and implementations to work without calling the base class' `__init__` method.

Also you can actually *use* that call to populate the list with your dice objects:

```
class Hands(list):
    def __init__(self, size=0, die_factory=None):
        if not die_factory:
            raise ValueError('You must provide a die factory')
        super().__init__(die_factory() for _ in range(size))
```

I've renamed `die_class` to `die_factory` as any callable that produces a new die object can be used here.

Note: You may violate the *is-a* relationship between `Hands` and `list` here unless a `Hands` object actually is a `list`, i.e. *all* methods and behaviour of lists also make sense for `Hands` objects.

Answer (score -1):

`super()` lets you avoid referring to the base class explicitly. More importantly, with multiple inheritance, you can do stuff like [this](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236275). At the end of the day, it is not necessary, it's just good practice.