# Inheritence from buitin class in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, built-in

How does johny gets the functionality of list even if the third line in the code is commented, as it is the initialisation?So then what is the significance of that line?

```
class Namedlist(list):
    def __init__(self,name):
          list.__init__([])  #This line even if commented does not affect the output
          self.name=name

johny=Namedlist(john)
johny.append("artist")
print(johny.name)
print(johny)

>>john
>>artist
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What are you trying to do?

Comment: For what is the third line in code used as it doesn't affect the output of the code even if it is removed or commented. That's it.

Comment: Pass `self` (not `[]`) to `list.__init__`, if you choose not to use `super`.

Comment: But even without using super or list.__init__ the johny object gets functionality of list.How is that?

Answer (score 1):

The line in your code `list.__init__([])` does nothing because you if you want to modify the object you are instantiating, you need to call `super()` not the `list` built-in (or use `list.__init__(self, [])`, but that seems more confusing to me).

The call to `super().__init__()` is usefull to pass along initial data for the list, for example.

I suggest you change your code to this:

```
class NamedList(list):
    def __init__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
          # pass any other arguments to the parent '__init__()'
          super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

          self.name = name
```

To be user like this:

```
>>> a = NamedList('Agnes', [2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> a.name
'Agnes'
>>> a
[2, 3, 4, 5]

>>> b = NamedList('Bob')
>>> b.name
'Bob'
>>> b
[]
>>> b.append('no')
>>> b.append('name')
>>> b
['no', 'name']
```

Any iterable works as initial data, not just lists:

```
>>> c = NamedList('Carl', 'Carl')
>>> c.name
'Carl'
>>> c
['C', 'a', 'r', 'l']
```

Comment: But even without using super or list.__init__ the johny object gets functionality of list.How is that?

Comment: @VedantBhosale Because it inherits from `list` (the class definition is `class NamedList(list):`). The call to `__init__()` is only object initialization; the methods on the object (for example `.append()`) exist regardless of the call to `super.__init__()` in the `NamedList.__init__()` method.

Comment: Initialization is done to inherit different attributes which are already defined in base class but here base class is a list so why is initialization done in this code?

Comment: @VedantBhosale in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46324470/9225671) there are a few explanations of why you should call the superclass' `__init__()` even though the call is not strictly necessary